# The request is not supported. Encrypting an Image in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, encryption

I am trying to create a simple encryption program with visual basic on visual studio. My program is to encrypt an image then decrypt it. The system is saying that the request is not supported. As a note I am just learning about encrypting and not sure if I am even doing this correctly. Any comments or help would be much appreciated.

Error is from this: File.Encrypt(FileName)
if my encrypt is creating an error then my decrypt will most likely as well

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    'My Encrypt button that takes the file from my FileUpload tool and Encrypts it, then outputs on my label
    'that the file was successfully encrypted
    Protected Sub EncryptButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EncryptButton.Click
        Dim FileName As String = FileUpload1.FileName
        File.Encrypt(FileName)
        Label1.Text = "Encrypt" + FileName
    End Sub
    'My Decrypt button that takes the file from my FileUpload tool and Encrypts it, then outputs on my label
    'that the file was successfully encrypted
    Protected Sub DecryptButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DecryptButton.Click
        Dim FileName As String = FileUpload1.FileName
        File.Decrypt(FileName)
        Label1.Text = "Decrypt" + FileName
    End Sub
    'Load page that will display a success output on the label if the upload is completed 
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If FileUpload1.HasFile = True Then
            Label1.Text = "Success"
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Failed"
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles CustomValidator1.ServerValidate
        'Verify the control has a file
        If Not FileUpload1.HasFile Then
            CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage = "A file is required in order to proceed"
            args.IsValid = False
        Else
            'next 2 lines are all one line
            Dim ext As String =
           System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToUpper()
            If Not ext = ".GIF" And Not ext = ".JPG" And Not ext = ".PNG" Then
                'next 2 lines are all one line
                CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage = String.Concat("Invalid file type '", ext, "' -must be .gif or .jpg or .png to continue")
                args.IsValid = False
            Else
                args.IsValid = True
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is the *exact* error message? You can see the reasons for the errors it can produce in the documentation at [File.Encrypt Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.encrypt(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The error I an getting is "The request is not supported.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The request is not supported."

Comment: Could this be because I an using filename as a String but then trying to use an image? Is there a certain type for images or would I need to convert it into some else?

Answer (score 0):

I searched for "System.IO.IOException" and found [Troubleshooting Exceptions: System.IO.IOException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164917.aspx) which states

> **Make sure the file and directory exist.**

Then looking at the code:

```
Dim FileName As String = FileUpload1.FileName
```

I see that there is no directory specified for the file. So, you need to use [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) so that you can give File.Encrypt the full filename including the path.

(There is no indiction in the posted code of which directory the uploaded file is in, so I can't help further with that. It could be that `FileUpload1` has a property which gives that.)